# Notification Bar not dismissing after device restart

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created notification bar

> Notification notification = new Notification(logoId, "ABC", System
>           .currentTimeMillis());
>
> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
> notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "PQR", "", pendingIntent);
> notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
> ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(
>     Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
> ```

if device forcefully restart notification still appearing after boot up.

i need to dismiss the notification bar if device restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Notification notification = new Notification(logoId, "ABC", System .currentTimeMillis());

Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "PQR", "", pendingIntent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(
    Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: i tried this one.. when user clear the notification it removing from notification tray...

Comment: then what you want excatly?

Comment: i dont want to clear notification by user forcefully. my issue is that. when user restart device still the notification available in notification tray.